# Error during compilation / installation of libcontainer due to custom-build kernel

Tags: go, docker, containers

I did a git clone of master at libcontainer and then followed through the CONTRIBUTING.md guide.

```
./update-vendor.sh
go get -d ./...
make direct-build
# Run the tests
make direct-test-short | egrep --color 'FAIL|$'
# Run all the test
make direct-test | egrep --color 'FAIL|$'
```

THe output of "make direct-build" gives:

```
    go build -v . ./apparmor ./cgroups ./cgroups/fs ./cgroups/systemd ./configs ./configs/validate ./criurpc ./devices ./integration ./label ./netlink ./nsenter ./nsinit ./seccomp ./selinux ./stacktrace ./system ./user ./utils ./xattr
    github.com/docker/libcontainer/cgroups/systemd
<xxxxx>
    # github.com/docker/libcontainer/cgroups/systemd
    /sda10/gopath/src/github.com/docker/libcontainer/cgroups/systemd/apply_systemd.go:87: not enough arguments in call to theConn.StartTransientUnit
    /sda10/gopath/src/github.com/docker/libcontainer/cgroups/systemd/apply_systemd.go:102: not enough arguments in call to theConn.StopUnit
    /sda10/gopath/src/github.com/docker/libcontainer/cgroups/systemd/apply_systemd.go:121: not enough arguments in call to theConn.StartTransientUnit
    /sda10/gopath/src/github.com/docker/libcontainer/cgroups/systemd/apply_systemd.go:130: not enough arguments in call to theConn.StopUnit
    /sda10/gopath/src/github.com/docker/libcontainer/cgroups/systemd/apply_systemd.go:201: not enough arguments in call to theConn.StartTransientUnit
    /sda10/gopath/src/github.com/docker/libcontainer/cgroups/systemd/apply_systemd.go:272: not enough arguments in call to theConn.StopUnit
    _/home/tthtlc/libcontainer/label
    # _/home/tthtlc/libcontainer/cgroups/systemd
    cgroups/systemd/apply_systemd.go:87: not enough arguments in call to theConn.StartTransientUnit
    cgroups/systemd/apply_systemd.go:102: not enough arguments in call to theConn.StopUnit
    cgroups/systemd/apply_systemd.go:121: not enough arguments in call to theConn.StartTransientUnit
    cgroups/systemd/apply_systemd.go:130: not enough arguments in call to theConn.StopUnit
    cgroups/systemd/apply_systemd.go:201: not enough arguments in call to theConn.StartTransientUnit
    cgroups/systemd/apply_systemd.go:272: not enough arguments in call to theConn.StopUnit
    make: *** [direct-build] Error 2
```

I tried this:

```
go get github.com/tools/godep
go get -d github.com/google/cadvisor
```

All returned without errors. Likely cause is "docker -d" daemon not starting up.

More details:

```
docker version
Client version: 1.7.0-dev
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 5e06332
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.19/version: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

"docker -d" is not able to succeed because my linux kernel is custom build (4.2.0-rc4+, and CONFIG_AUFS_FS is completely absent from my config tree option as it has been deprecated and removed).

Any ideas on how to proceed?